# Scala type inference does not work with type bounds, unless the type is specified explicitly

Tags: scala, function, scala-cats

I'm trying to create a documentation wrapper around functions in scala like, so that the wrapper can be queried for its containing function's documentation, like so:

```
trait WrappedFunction1[A, B] {
  def f : Function1[A, B]
  def doc: String
  def apply(x:A):B = f(x)
  def compose[C, T <:WrappedFunction1[B, C]](that:T):WrappedFunction1[A, C] = 
    new Wrapper[A, C](this.f andThen that.f, this.doc + " composed with " + that.doc)
}

class Wrapper[A, B](f1:Function1[A, B], sos:String) extends WrappedFunction1[A, B] {
  val f = f1
  val doc = sos
}

object Wrapper {
  implicit class Wrap[A, B](f1:Function1[A, B]) {
    def wrap(sos:String):WrappedFunction1[A, B] = new Wrapper(f1, sos)
  }
}
```

Here's how I'd use this:

```
import Wrapper._
val x : String => String = _.toLowerCase
val y : String => String = _.toUpperCase
val x1 = x.wrap("a function for lowercasing")
val y1 = y.wrap("a function for uppercasing")

println(x1("LOL")) // lol
println(x1.doc) // a function for lowercasing
```

However, I cant get the type inferred when I compose two of these:

```
val xy = x1 compose y1

cmd3.sc:1: inferred type arguments [Nothing,cmd3Wrapper.this.cmd1.cmd0.wrapper.WrappedFunction1[String,String]] do not conform to method compose's type parameter bounds [C,T <: cmd3Wrapper.this.cmd1.cmd0.wrapper.WrappedFunction1[String,C]]
val xy = x1 compose y1
            ^cmd3.sc:1: type mismatch;
 found   : cmd3Wrapper.this.cmd1.cmd0.wrapper.WrappedFunction1[String,String]
 required: T
val xy = x1 compose y1
                    ^
Compilation Failed
```

Composing them works if I explicitly state the types:

```
val xy = x1 compose[String, WrappedFunction1[String, String]] y1
```

Is there somewhere I'm going wrong?
Also is there a better way to do this? (I tried typeclasses but they seem to be defined for traits with one type param, any other algebraic datatype perhaps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in details of Scala's type inference. It can't infer `T` first and then infer `C` from it; instead it has to infer both at once.

From `that: T` it can determine `T`, but `C` isn't mentioned in parameter types, so it's assigned `Nothing` and only on the next step the compiler notices it doesn't fit. So the fix is to change the type to

```
def compose[C, T <:WrappedFunction1[B, C]](that: T with WrappedFunction1[B, C])
```

Or better, simply

```
def compose[C](that: WrappedFunction1[B, C])
```

because this already allows to pass any subtype of `WrappedFunction1[B, C]`!